# Python Numpy: How to assign two results if np.where condition is satisfied?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, debugging

**Input Explained:** Got DataFrame `df`

```
Category    Location    Min     Space
AA          Y           0.25    0.25
BB          Y           0.25    1
CC                      0.5     0.625
```

**Scenario:**
Have to calculate `Reduced_Space` for located category `'Y'` with `loc_perc`, but if `Reduced_Space` is lesser than `Min` have to retain same `Space` as original and update `Location` column for that category to '  '.

**Expected Output:**

```
Category    Location    Min     Space   Reduced_Space   
AA                      0.25    0.25    0.25
BB          Y           0.25    1       0.5
CC                      0.5     0.625   0.625
```

**Tried Code:**
Not sure how to assign two values if a condition satisfies in `np.where`. Have used 'and' as connector but throws error like keywords can't be used here.

```
loc_perc = 0.5

dfNew = df.assign(
    temp=lambda x: x.Space,
    Reduced_Space=lambda x: np.where(x.Location == "Y", 
                            np.where((x.Space * dual_loc_perc) < x.Min, x.Space and x.Dual_Location ='', x.Space * dual_loc_perc)
                            , x.Space),  
).drop("temp", 1)
```

Need help! Thank in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

I think you need processing each column separately, here is possible chain both condition by `&` for bitwise `AND`:

```
dual_loc_perc = 0.5

m1 = df.Location == "Y"
m2 = (df.Space * dual_loc_perc) < df.Min

df['Reduced_Space'] = np.where(m1 & m2, df.Space, df.Space * dual_loc_perc) 

df.loc[m1 & m2, 'Location'] = ''
print (df)
  Category Location   Min  Space  Reduced_Space
0       AA           0.25  0.250         0.2500
1       BB        Y  0.25  1.000         0.5000
2       CC           0.50  0.625         0.3125
```